# How to copy .jar of one repository to another repository in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am using azure CI CD pipeline for build and deploy.
I am generating the abc.jar artifacts from A azure repository and I want to copy this artifact in another azure repository B (Both A and B repo are in same project)and then want to build repository B and then deploy.

I tried downloading artifacts manually and placing it in other repo. However I want this to be done automatically. Could you please help in how can I copy .jar of one repository to another?

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

- [pipeline resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-pipelines) - here you define your pipeline A as resource, you can also trigger pipeline B when pipeline A ends (or some stage in pipeline A even)
- task [DownloadBuildArtifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops)
- task [DownloadPipelineArtifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops)

```yaml
name: pipelineB

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: hadar
    source: kmadof.hadar
    branch: master
    trigger:
      branches:
        - master
steps:
  - script: env | sort
  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
    inputs:
      buildType: 'specific'
      project: '4fa6b279-3db9-4cb0-aab8-e06c2ad550b2'
      pipeline: '72'
      branchName: 'refs/heads/master'
      buildVersionToDownload: 'specific'
      downloadType: 'single'
      downloadPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/build'
      artifactName: 'drop'
      buildId: '$(resources.pipeline.hadar.runID)'

  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    inputs:
      buildType: 'specific'
      project: '4fa6b279-3db9-4cb0-aab8-e06c2ad550b2'
      definition: '72'
      specificBuildWithTriggering: true
      buildVersionToDownload: 'specific'
      pipelineId: '$(resources.pipeline.hadar.runID)'
      artifactName: 'drop'
      targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/pipeline'
  - download: hadar
```

So you don't have to add you artifact to any repo. I recommend you use resources.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I tried to use pipeline as resource and able to consume the generated artifact. However I want to copy the build artifacts of repo 'A' in particular directory(/demo/static) in repo B. How that can be achieved?

Comment: You should use [`DownloadPipelineArtifact@2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) you have a path settings there. Please bear in mind that `download` is just a shortcut for this task. Or you can use [Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).